# Using "learning python the hard way." string formatting issue

Tags: python

is the code he wants me to enter that fails

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv
prompt = '> '

print "Hi %s, I'm the %s script." % (user_name, script)
print "I'd like to ask you a few questions."
print "Do you like me %s?" % user_name
likes = raw_input(prompt)
```

is the code I modified after seeing errors  and knowing he uses python 2, I've just been making corrections to his code as I find them online.

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv
prompt = '> '

print ("Hi" user_name: %s, "I/'m the", %s: script.)
print ("I;d like tok ask you a few questions")
print ("Do you like me %s") % (user_name)
likes = input(prompt)
```

---

All `%s`, `%d` `%r` have failed for me.  Is this a python 2 convention?  Should I be using something else?

for example

```
foo = bar 
print ("the variable foo %s is a fundamental programming issue.)
```

I have tried using tuples?  as in:

```
print ("the variable foo", %s: foo, "is a fundamental programming issue.")
```

with no success

Comment: Note that you need to format the string **before** passing it to the `print` function: `print("Do you like me %s" % user_name)`. Otherwise you're trying `None % user_name`...

Comment: You use the `%` operator on the return value of `print`. It should look like this: `print("Do you like me %s" % user_name)`.

Comment: Duplicate of e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23372824/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/22070888/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7081905/3001761, etc... **Google your error messages**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Comment: Honestly, there should be a tag for Learning Python the Hard Way. The five most abhorred words to a Python programmer.

Comment: I did Google the error

Comment: Sorry for dupes.  I'll try to search more thoroughly before posting next time.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use [string.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format)

For example:

```
some_string = 'My name is {name} and i live in {location}'
some_params = {
    'name': 'Tim',
    'location': 'Germany'
}

print(some_string.format(**some_params))
```

Which will result in

```
My name is Tim and i live in Germany
```

For a more specific documentation, look at the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)

Nevermind, the problems in your second example are:

- Remove the gap between `print` and the starting bracket `(`
- Build the strings before the print statement. Sometimes it looks like there are missing `&`, `*` and `%S`'s

Comment: Although this is certainly a better approach, it doesn't actually explain the OP's current problem.

Answer (score 0):

As said by tim we can use string.format()

For formatting the string you can use index also. i.e., Your code will be look like the below one,

```
from sys import argv

script = argv[0]
user_name = argv[1]


print "Hi {0} I am the Script {1}".format(user_name,script)
print ("I;d like tok ask you a few questions")
print "Do you like me {0}".format(user_name)
```

Comment: Thanks.   You all have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your issue as when using brackets with print all formatting should be inside of the brackets:

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv

prompt = '> '

print ("Hi %s, Im the %s" % (user_name, script))

print ("I;d like tok ask you a few questions")

print("Do you like me %s" % (user_name))

likes = input(prompt)
```